# Implementing Fragment View

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, zxing

**Update Solved**

I was implenting the wrong view when trying to inflate the fragment, This lead to the incorrect and pointer error. rootview was changed to the below with the correct layout

```
        rootview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main_layout, container, false);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, any statements you place after the return statement turns into an unreachable one. The return statement should be the last statement in onCreateView, after you have initialized your views.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I actually solved the error, had the return in the wrong place as you said but now I am faced with another error, I have updated the question